# How can I disable the view of a page for other users?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, user-roles

I want that a user of my application to enable or disable the viewing of a certain page for other users. For that i need , somehow an application variable, a bool to be set true or false whether the user decides to enable or disable the view for other users.

The functionality that i want is : when i click on a button to disable the view for a page(**for other users that are connected to site**), and when i press back to enable it .

I can achieve this with the use of a database, by changing the value of a field in a table with true or false.But this approach is ineffective and not elegant.

Can someone tell me how I can achieve this without using databases ? Is there any application variable / session variable / or cookie to achieve this ? Is there something that i should write in Global.asax ?

I use ASP.NET MVC 4..

Please help!

Comment: Can you please specify, what trial(s) you did were not yielding expected result? Did you try with caching to reduce the database trips?

Comment: i did store the value in a database, with one table and one field with values true or false. I don't want to create a table with one field in my database for this functionality. I'm trying to find another way to solve this problem... A more elegant one.. Mine is kinda hardcoded..

Comment: why did i get downvote ? i think it's a legitimate question ...

Comment: If you want to persist the value, your going to have to store it somewhere, whether its a database or an xml file. Session is no good because that's per user (another user could not access it)

Comment: Cookies are per use as well. How would another user know your cookie values or vice versa?

Comment: what do you mean when you say cookies are per use ? You meant per user ?

Comment: I solved it. I stored the data into an xml and it's much more elegant..

Answer (score -1):

In you Controller declare "static variable" say

```
static bool disableViewPage;
```

Set this value on click of button in the some action.

Example :

```
public class SomeViewController : Controller
{
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult DisableView(bool value)// on button click
   {
      SecondController.DisableViewPage=value;
      return View("<SomeView>")
   }

}

public class SecondController : Controller
{
   public static bool DisableViewPage;
   // your views

}
```

Comment: the problem is that the controller i have the button is different from the controller i have the page that will be disabled...

Comment: You can access that varible using the class name. as it is static and public.

Comment: @SeeTheC The question is for an elegant approach and its not a good practice to assign controller properties etc since instantiation & Dependency Injection(if used) etc., would get messed up.

Comment: I can't save the values in static variable because I need persistent data. I need the page to be disabled even when i close my session.

Comment: In one of my applicant I uses Db and static class object. I need lot of value to cached at local side . So I did is , on start of application, I fetched all values from DB and stored in this static object for avoiding multiple DB fetch . When ever there is change in values I just update my object and also Db